# What is the difference between these two AND Operators in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, where-clause

```sql
AND (
     (mmd.TerminationDate IS NOT NULL AND mmd.TerminationDate >= '01-Jan-2019')
     OR mmd.TerminationDate IS NULL
)
```

```sql
AND (mmd.TerminationDate IS NULL OR mmd.TerminationDate >= '01-Jan-2020')
```

Comment: Did you make a typo ? One condition states 01-Jan-2020 while the other is 01-Jan-2019

Comment: Have you checked query plans?

Comment: There is no difference: let's assume a = `mmd.TerminationDate is NULL`, b = `mmd.TerminationDate >= '01-Jan-2019'`. (not a ∧ b) ∨ a = (not a ∨ a) ∧ (b ∨ a) = b ∨ a = a ∨ b. In terms of boolean logic there is no difference between theese two conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the literal dates are supposed to be the same, both conditions do the same thing - that is, allow dates that are either null or greater than January 1st.

The first expression is unecessarily redundant:

```
(mmd.TerminationDate is NOT NULL and mmd.TerminationDate >= '01-Jan-2019') 
or mmd.TerminationDate is null)
```

If `TerminationDate` is `null`, then it cannot be greater than January 1st, so the first subcondition actually boils down to `mmd.TerminationDate >= '01-Jan-2019'`.

Unrelated note: although SQL Server is quite flexible about understanding date formats, I would use a more standard format to represent January first, like:

```
mmd.TerminationDate is Null OR mmd.TerminationDate >= '2019-01-01'
```

Comment: Sometimes these redundancies make SQL Server pick a better execution plan and/or consider a filtered index.

Comment: Your answer is correct assuming both conditions where checked against 01-Jan-2019, but in his question he is comparing two different queries one with 2019 the other with 2020. Probably that is why he is confused.

Comment: @GabrielDurac: ah yes, you are correct, I did not ntice the difference in the year at first. I would assume that's a typo - otherwise the question makes less sense to me!

Comment: Aside: Do you mean [literal](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/literal) or [littoral](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/littoral)? Pandemics make many people want to head for the beach.

Comment: @HABO: ah ah good one... Thanks. I think I do that typo quite often.